# How to find this $\sum^{63}_{r=1} \{ (-1)^{r+1} r^2 \} =$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Request you to please elaborate, how to find this :

$\sum^{63}_{r=1} \{ (-1)^{r+1} r^2 \} =$

Answer (score 3):

$$
\sum_{r=1}^{63} (-1)^{r+1} r^2 = 1 + \sum_{r=1}^{31} ((2r+1)^2 - (2r)^2) = 1 + \sum_{r=1}^{31} (4r +1)
$$
Can you continue?